# How can I create a Graphic Geometry back form list of MapPoints

Tags: .net, arcgis, esri, arcgis-runtime-net

I retrieved a list of Points from a Polygon the following way;

```
    public Graphic Graphic { get; set; }
    public List<MapPoint> MapPoint { get; set; }
    MapPoint = new List<MapPoint>();
    ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.PointCollection points = null;
    if (Graphic.Geometry is Polygon)
    {
        points = ((Polygon)Graphic.Geometry).Rings[0];
        foreach (MapPoint mapPoint in points)
        {
            //Save the points  
            MapPoint.Add(mapPoint);
        }
    }
```

Now my use case requires appending this Geometry back to the Graphic after a serialization/deserialization of the attribute of List(). Since rings are part of a Polygon and Polygon has a constructor that accepts a list of Map Points I would guess the following code works, but it doesn't compile.

**Polygon class** : https://developers.arcgis.com/net/10-2/desktop/api-reference/html/M_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_Polygon__ctor_4.htm

How can I get the rings back into the Graphic attribute?

```
            List<MapPoint> mapPoint = null;
            Polygon myPolygon = null;
            foreach(Atribution at in sc. Atribution)
            {
                foreach(AtributionContour atContour in at.Contours)
                {
                    myPolygon = new Polygon(new List<MapPoint>( AtributionContour.MapPoint.ToList()));

                    //Append polygon to a Geometry


                    //Append geometry to graphic
                }

            }
```

**Error**

*Error  CS1729  'Polygon' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments*

Answer (score 1):

Use the constructor that takes a collection of a collection of points. One collection of points for each ring:
https://developers.arcgis.com/net/10-2/desktop/api-reference/html/M_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_Polygon__ctor_5.htm